# Question about estimating the standard error of the regression- notation and intuition

Tags: regression, estimation, standard-error, notation

in a standard linear regression frame work:

$y_{i}=\beta x_i + \epsilon_i$

when calculating standard errors, we find an unbiased and consistent estimator of $var(\hat{\beta})$. Assume spherical errors. so typically we need :

$E[\epsilon  \epsilon']$, which is a diagonal matrix.
Now if I understand correctly, the element on the $ith$ diagonal/entry is then $E[\epsilon_i  \epsilon_i']$, with the transpose on the second epsilon. we write this as $\sigma^2$. but when we go to estimate sigma, we usually use:

$e'e/(n-k)$

where e is the residual. Why is it e'e if the diagonal term is $\epsilon_i  \epsilon_i'$? I think the tranpose (') notation is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume spherical errors. so typically we need :
> $E[\epsilon\epsilon′]$, which is a diagonal matrix.

It would be nice, but you can never observe $\epsilon$. You *assume* $E[\epsilon\epsilon′]=\sigma^2I$.

> the element on the ith diagonal/entry is then $E[\epsilon_i\epsilon′_i]$, with the
> transpose on the second epsilon

$\epsilon_i$ is a single random variable, so it is equal to $\epsilon_i'$.

> we write this as σ2 but when we go to estimate sigma, we usually use:
> $e′e/(n−k)$ where e is the residual.

Don't be hasty :)

First step: in a standard linear regression framework, $y=X\beta+\epsilon$, $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2I)$, $V[y]=V[\epsilon]=\sigma^2I$.

Second step: $\hat\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, and
$$V[\hat\beta]=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TV[y]X(X^TX)^{-1}=(X^TX)^{-1}\sigma^2$$
($X^TX$ is a symmetric matrix.)

Third step: since you can't observe $\epsilon$, the best you can do is to use residuals.
\begin{align*}
e&=y-X\hat\beta=y-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty=y-Hy=(I-H)y \\
E[e]&=E[y]-E[X\hat\beta]=E[y]-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TE[y]\\
&=X\beta-X(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX)y=0\\
V[e]&=(I-H)\sigma^2
\end{align*}
where $H=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ and $I-H$ are symmetric and idempotent matrices. The residual sum of squares is:
$$RSS=e'e=y^T(I-H)^T(I-H)y=y^T(I-H)y$$
The trace of $H$ is equal to the rank of $X$, i.e. $k$, the number of columns. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582567/proof-that-trace-of-hat-matrix-in-linear-regression-is-rank-of-x). The trace of $I-H$, an $n\times n$ matrix, is $n-k$.
The residual mean square,
$$RMS=\frac{e'e}{n-k}$$
is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$:
\begin{align*}
E[e'e]&\overset{[1]}{=}E[\text{trace}(e'e)]\overset{[2]}{=}E[\text{trace}(ee')]=\text{trace}(E[ee'])\\&=\text{trace}(V[e])=\text{trace}(I-H)\sigma^2=(n-k)\sigma^2\\
E[RMS]&=\frac{E[e'e]}{n-k}=\frac{(n-k)\sigma^2}{n-k}=\sigma^2
\end{align*}
So the estimated variance of $\hat\beta$ is:
$$\hat{V}[\hat\beta]=(X^TX)^{-1}RMS$$
Putting $S=(X^TX)^{-1}$, the standard error of $\hat\beta_j$ is $\sqrt{s_{jj}RMS}$.

---

[1] $e'e$ is a scalar, so $\text{trace}(e'e)=e'e$.
[2] If $e=(a,b,c)$, then $e'e=\text{trace}(e'e)=a^2+b^2+c^2$, and $$ee'=\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a^2 & ab & ac \\ ab & b^2 & bc \\ ac & ab & c^2\end{bmatrix},\quad\text{trace}(ee')=a^2+b^2+c^2$$